# Alternate gathering info from columns in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet, with items using data validation from a dropdown. B5:B24, then in A5:A24, is for a count.

Example
A5 = 2 B5 = apples
A6 = 5 B6 = oranges.

In another cell, I'm using 
={JOIN( " | " , FILTER(B5:B24, NOT(B5:B24 = "") )) & JOIN( " x " , FILTER(A5:A24, NOT(A5:A24 = "") ))}

but it's returning:
apples | oranges | 2 x 5 x

What I'm trying to get it to return is:
2 x apples | 5 x oranges

How could I go about getting that working?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(join(" | ",filter(A5:A24,A5:A24<>"")&" x "&filter(B5:B24,B5:B24<>"")))
```